# Transformation inside while loop- BPEL 10g

Tags: xslt, soa, bpel

Requirement is read data from file and invoke webservice. Target webservice can handle one payload at a time but there will be multiple payload in source.
So am using while loop to process payload one by one.

Issue: In target service EarningTypeInclusion is optional element, so in source some payload this element will be present and in some payload this option element will not be present.

```
<thresholdRequestInterface xmlns:xs="http://www.sample.com/ns/LMSReferrals">
<thresholdRequest>
<Referral>11</Referral>
<thresholdValue>100</thresholdValue>
<EarningTypeInclusion>
<earningType>positive</earningType>
<ProvisionId>1000</ProvisionId>
</EarningTypeInclusion>
</thresholdRequest>
<thresholdRequest>
<Referral>11</Referral>
<thresholdValue>100</thresholdValue>
</thresholdRequest>
</thresholdRequestInterface>
```

If am using assign activity, then selection failure fault will come when optional elements are not present in source payload. We are using BPEL 10g, no option in assign activity to supress selection failure fault.
So decided to use transformation inside while loop .

## logic used

Read from file

assign Loop counter=1

Count of payload(read from file)

While loop counter<= Count of payload

pass loop counter param value to transform

transform source i.e thresholdRequest[loopcounter] to target

Invoke target web service

increment loop counter

end loop;

Problem is same data is getting trsnformed.

In the below example, referral 11 data is loading 3 times. I have checked conter value, its getting incremented but inside transformation same values are getting transformed.

```
<thresholdRequestInterface xmlns:xs="http://www.sample.com/ns/LMSReferrals">
<thresholdRequest>
<Referral>11</Referral>
<thresholdValue>100</thresholdValue>
<EarningTypeInclusion>
<earningType>positive</earningType>
<ProvisionId>1000</ProvisionId>
</EarningTypeInclusion>
</thresholdRequest>
<thresholdRequest>
<Referral>12</Referral>
<thresholdValue>100</thresholdValue>
</thresholdRequest>
<thresholdRequest>
<Referral>13</Referral>
<thresholdValue>100</thresholdValue>
<EarningTypeInclusion>
<earningType>positive</earningType>
<ProvisionId>1000</ProvisionId>
</EarningTypeInclusion>
</thresholdRequest>
</thresholdRequestInterface>
```

## Source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.sample.com/ns/LMSReferrals" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.sample.com/ns/LMSReferrals" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="thresholdRequestInterface">
  <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="thresholdRequest" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element  name="Referral" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element  name="thresholdValue" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element  name="EarningTypeInclusion" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="earningType" type="xs:stirng" />
              <xs:element name="ProvisionId">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="20" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Please find the schema structure for source and target

## Target

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.sample.com/ns/LMSReferrals" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.sample.com/ns/LMSReferrals" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="thresholdRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element  name="Referral" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element  name="thresholdValue" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element  name="EarningTypeInclusion" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="earningType" type="xs:stirng" />
              <xs:element name="ProvisionId">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="20" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Please note schema validation is enabled at target webservice.

Comment: Hi, have you ensured the variable `thresholdRequest` actually holds the three different referrals and not the same referral three times, i.e. the issue is not the `read from file` step?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason that you are using Transform.Try using ora:getElement('/thresholdRequestInterface /thresholdRequest',bpws:getVariable(loopCounter))

Comment: This is not an answer!